# Memory issue and duplicate in my C# program

Tags: c#

can someone help me fix this specific block of code?

This is my issue. I wrote a program that acts in a similar fashion as Windows Explorer, which gives me an hierarchy of files and folder within the hard drive and all other drives in a computer.

This piece of code below seemed to have an issue with running the program smoothly. When I start the program, the program starts off very slow and it takes a long while until it finally load. This is due to the fact that my program is going through all my files and folders before finally loading it. This can be bothersome for computers with lots of data.

I'm able to fix the problem by commenting out the two lines at the try block. But when I run the program and I open up a drive, it duplicates (example: when I expand C:/ drive, and then I collapse the C:/ drive, a duplicate of the C:/ drive shows up in the program)

Here are the images below.

image1

[image: image1]

image2

[image: image2]

And this is the piece of code I'm talking about. If you guys want the full code please let me know.

```
 private void GetDirectories(DirectoryInfo[] subDirs, TreeNode nodeToAddTo)
    {
        TreeNode aNode;
        DirectoryInfo[] subSubDirs;
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in subDirs)
        {      
            aNode = new TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0);
            aNode.Tag = subDir;
            aNode.ImageKey = "folder";
            try
            {
                //subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories();
                //GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode);
                nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("none"); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not recursively map the whole directory, this results in long running code. Instead try to load a folders Children as soon as it is expanded.
Also your Code might have problems, with non permitted directories.

Answer (score 0):

This code should not be written recuresively. This is the problem. Let's say that you have 100 directories. Every directory has 100 subdirectories. Every subdirectory has 100 sub-subdirectories. That's quite a lot. But does the user want to see deepest directory? No. He wants to see directories in the directory he is now. So you should list only directories and files that are in selected node.

So don't build the whole tree on startup. Just list main directories. And when user clicks a directory, list only it's subdirectories.